# move menu navigation icon to top of page

Tags: css

I am unable to move the menu navigation icon to the top of the page so it's just below the title at the moment. How would I move it to the top of the page so it's inline with the title? I would like the vertical menu to overlay the other contents when it's opened.

UPDATE: I've attached all of the code below so you can run it and see what's happening.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
      x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
```

```css
 body {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
    .offers, .the-offer, .offer-date {
      text-align: center;
    }
    .name {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
      color: #2f416d;
      font-size: 29px;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .site-name {
      color: #2f416d;
      margin-top: -40px;
      margin-right: 15px;
      text-align: right;
    }

    /* NAV BAR */

    /* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
    .topnav {
        background-color: white;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-top: -10px;
        /* border-top: #2f416d solid 2px; */
        display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
    }

    /* Hide the links inside the navigation menu (except for logo) */
    .topnav #myLinks {
      overflow: hidden;
      display: none;
      margin-left: 36px;
    }
    .topnav a {
      color:#2f416d;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
      display: block;
    }
    .topnav a.icon {
       background: #94ceca; 
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      padding: 13.5px;
      /* right: 0;
      top: 0; */
    } 
    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: #2f416d;
      color: black;
    } 

    /* Style the active link (or home/logo) */
    .active {
      background-color: #94ceca;
      color: #2f416d;
    }
      .topnav a {
        display: flex; 
        text-align: center;
        padding: 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      } 
      .topnav a:hover {
        color: #94ceca;
      }
      .topnav a.active {
        color: #9ba0ac;
      }
      .about-head {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
      }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300|Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Load an icon library to show a hamburger menu (bars) on small screens -->   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1 class="name">cdbicdnsiu</h1>
    <h4 class="site-name">biaksncdjk - ENGLAND</h5>

    <!-- Top Navigation Menu -->
    <div class="topnav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
          </a>
          <!-- "Hamburger menu" / "Bar icon" to toggle the navigation links -->
      <!-- Navigation links (hidden by default) -->
      <div id="myLinks">
          <a class="active" href="#home"><strong>HOME</strong></a>
          <a href="about.html"><strong>ABOUT</strong></a>
          <a href="testimonials.html"><strong>TESTIMONIALS</strong></a>
          <a href="prices.html"><strong>PRICES</strong></a>
          <a href="offers.html"><strong>OFFERS</strong></a>
          <a href="contact.html"><strong>CONTACT</strong></a>
      </div>
      </div>
    </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Please provide us with all the html and css needed to replicate the problem, so we can try to fix it

Comment: for now it's unclear what is happening

Comment: To see exactly what's going on, you will need to post the HTML code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the .topnav div on top of the site and site-name divs, then change these classes:

```
.name {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2f416d;
  font-size: 29px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width: 99%;
}
.site-name {
  color: #2f416d;
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.topnav {
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* border-top: #2f416d solid 2px; */
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

The problem mainly was that you gave display: block at the .site div, so this div had full width and moved to the next line.

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/evelyng/pen/NWWxOmK).